# Bootstrap dropdown inactive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

what tricks may get my dropdown to work as i've tried other tricks but to no avail. The code is below. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>

    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="btn-group"> 
    <button id="myid" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable a menu item form the dropdown use the `disabled` class:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="/">Another action (disabled)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and prevent clicks usign jQuery:

```
<script>

    $(".disabled > a").click(function(event) {
      return false;
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
```

I think your CDNs might be giving you problems. Replace you `<head> </head>` with this ^ see if that works